# how to use greater than or less than in date in java i have two date in simple date format or as a string

Tags: java, android, date

i have date object i m getting date as date object and converted as a string object but now i have to validate if current date is equal to next date which i m getting  is greater then or less then

```
Date someDate = new Date(); // Or whatever
Date dayAfter = new Date(someDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis( 2 ));
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String DayafterdDate=dateFormat.format(dayAfter);
editoradddetail1.putString("days", formattedDate);
//current date  
Date date=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat();
Date today = new Date(date.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(0 ));
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String todaydDate=dateFormat.format(today);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare two dates with number of ways.
But you can use any from below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
   //Your details
}
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {
  //Your details
}
```

Comment: thanks 2 one is easy to understand

Comment: Happy coding man :)

Comment: plz upgrate i m new so i can not upgrade to u i nead  15 raputation